psql prompting for password when PGPASSFILE (.pgpass) is being used
I am having trouble getting psql to use/recognise a .pgpass file, can anyone spot what's wrong? Using PGPASSWORD=P@ssw0rd works fine as expected:
# Passing PGPASSWORD=P@ssw0rd, works fine
bash-5.1# PGPASSWORD=P@ssw0rd psql --username=myuser --host=myserver.local --port=5432 --variable database_name=mydb
psql (16.4, server 14.12)
Type "help" for help.
myuser=> exit

But using PGPASSFILE=/root/.pgpass results in a password prompt:
# Using PGPASSFILE=/root/.pgpass, prompting for password when it should be using password in /root/.pgpass
bash-5.1# whoami
root

bash-5.1# ls -al /root/.pgpass
-rw-------. 1 root root 57 Oct 15 12:37 /root/.pgpass

bash-5.1# echo $PGPASSFILE
/root/.pgpass

bash-5.1# cat /root/.pgpass
myserver.local:5432:mydb:myuser:P@ssw0rd

bash-5.1# PGPASSFILE=/root/.pgpass psql --username=myuser --host=myserver.local --port=5432 --variable database_name=mydb
Password for user myuser:


what happens if you use the database name directly, e.g. without --variable stuff?

Fix provided by @jhole (use the database name directly, e.g. without --variable stuff):
Change:
PGPASSFILE=/root/.pgpass psql --username=myuser --host=myserver.local --port=5432 --variable database_name=mydb

to:
PGPASSFILE=/root/.pgpass psql --username=myuser --host=myserver.local --port=5432 -mydb

